# how to append a new key and value field in a multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array with the following format.
Example Json for reference:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.42c7485653ea40549da90cf4338f8b23

I want to add "super_parent_id" in each of the childData arrays.
So if childData exists, i need to append super_parent_id to that child array. Similarly if a childData array exists within that array, i need to append super_parent_id to that child array.

I think recursion can solve this issue but I am not sure how to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: That's not valid JSON nor a PHP array that someone can use to help you.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have added an example json to it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, correct, recursion is one of the approaches for the problem. Here is a code snippet explaining how to implement the recursive modification of such data structure.

```
function appendSuperParentId(&$elem, $superParentId){
    $elem["super_parent_id"] = $superParentId;
    if (isset($elem["childData"])){
        appendSuperParentId($elem["childData"], $superParentId);
    }
}

$elems = [
    [
        "name" => "xyz",
        "childData" => [
            "name" => "foo",
            "childData" => [
            ] 
        ]
    ]
];
for ($i = 0; i < count($elems); $i++){
    appendSuperParentId($elems[$i]["childData"], $superParentId);
}
```

not tested, but idea should work.

Comment: That not the way to answer - you need to explain how that fix the OP issue and what was he problem

Comment: @dWinder, expanded solution with the textual explanation of how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've a cleaner solution using `foreach`:

```
<?php
$data = array (
  'data' => 
  array (
    'valueId' => '21803826062',
    'hasChildren' => true,
    'parentId' => '21768700190',
    'name' => 'Test Unit 002',
    'childData' => 
    array (
      21810803918 => 
      array (
        'valueId' => '21810803918',
        'hasChildren' => false,
        'parentId' => '21803826062',
        'name' => 'Test Unit 003',
        'childData' => NULL,
        'adUnitCode' => 'Test_unit_003',
        'adUnitSizes' => NULL,
        'adType' => 'TEXT_AND_IMAGE',
        'smartSizeMode' => 'NONE',
      ),
      21810890245 => 
      array (
        'valueId' => '21810890245',
        'hasChildren' => false,
        'parentId' => '21803826062',
        'name' => 'Test Unit 002_1',
        'childData' => NULL,
        'adUnitCode' => 'test_unit_002_1',
        'adUnitSizes' => NULL,
        'adType' => 'TEXT_AND_IMAGE',
        'smartSizeMode' => 'NONE',
      ),
    ),
    'adUnitCode' => 'unit002',
    'adUnitSizes' => NULL,
    'adType' => 'TEXT_AND_IMAGE',
    'smartSizeMode' => 'NONE',
  ),
);
$parentId = $data['data']['parentId'];
foreach($data['data']['childData'] as $key => $value){
    $data['data']['childData'][$key]['super_parent_id'] = $parentId;
}

print_r($data);
```

PHP Sandbox [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2c688f2113cd9c196f4a892101765c566d59470)

Comment: This will not work properly in all cases,  s there could be nested childData elements, which was the part of the original question.